# MS Graph API: Requests must contain extension changes exclusively

Tags: outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-api

I want to add a data extension to an existing resource using the MS Graph API.

For that I make a `POST` request to following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[USER_ID]/events/[EVENT_ID]/extensions
```

with following request body:

```
{
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension",
        "extensionName": "[MY_EXTENSION_NAME]",
        "my_field": "my_value"
}
```

but from time to time, the only response I get is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Requests must contain extension changes exclusively.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "c10c8e95-dd89-455b-9a83-3d2441918618",
        "date": "2017-02-21T21:10:55"
    }
  }
}
```

What does this message means?

Found out, that following request works:

```
{
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension",
        "extensionName": "[MY_EXTENSION_NAME]"
}
```

so without any value for this extension point, which makes it kinda useless. The weirdest part is, that it worked with the value for several weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been getting this issue, but I think what is happening is that I'm using a patch message to update the extension. Because this is intermittent, I suspect that in some random cases the empty extensions are being added and then the API is allowing an update of a non-existent ID.
It sometimes gets caused when replying to a message, and other times it doesn't - in both cases this is outlook365 sender and recipient.

What probably needs to be done in my case is create the post message if the extension isn't found on my draft message, otherwise use the patch to update it.

I do find it incredibly peculiar that it works in some cases but not others. It strikes me that it should either work every time or not at all - not have some weird random possiblity of it happening.

Update: I've just tried doing it in graph explorer and I don't seem to be able to add the extension to a draft at all now.

Comment: I wasn't really offering this as an answer, but was too long for a comment - there's still an issue with this.